# How to forward logs using rsyslog client

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I need to forward messages from a log file to another IP - let's say `127.0.0.1 514`. How do I achieve this?

I used [this example](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html#configuration-examples) from the docs of rsyslog:

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10") #needs to be done just once



# File 2
input(type="imfile"
     File="/path/to/file2"
     Tag="tag2")
```

As well as providing it with the following rule:

```
*.*      @127.0.0.1:514
```

But this ended up sending all of the system's logs including journald.

So how do I correctly use ruleset, input blocks and `*.*      @127.0.0.1:514` to send logs from file `/path/to/file2` to `127.0.0.1:514`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying the input, also say which ruleset to apply. Input outside the ruleset will not be processed by the ruleset.

```
module(load="imfile")
input(type="imfile" File="/path/to/file2" Tag="tag2" ruleset="remote")
ruleset(name="remote"){
 action(type="omfwd" target="127.0.0.1" port="514" protocol="udp")
 # or use legacy syntax:
 # *.*  @127.0.0.1:514
}
```